# Hibernate: Auto-load classes marked as @Entity from jar from different classpath

Tags: java, hibernate

I have application (.war) which uses entities from other jar file from different classpath. My persistance.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="EAP" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/pscDataSource2</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.myPackage.entity.MyEntity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.myPackage.interceptor.DelegatingInterceptor" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

With this xml I load **MyEntity** class successfully. However I would like to avoid listing all necessary classes in persistance.xml file. What I've found is `<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />` But with such approach I need to list jar files from where I want to load entities. So my persistance.xml file now looks like below and works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="EAP" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/pscDataSource2</jta-data-source>

        <jar-file>lib/myJar.jar</jar-file> //new line

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.myPackage.interceptor.DelegatingInterceptor" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" /> //new line
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Question:** Is the any way to load entities from jars without listing them at all if I have dependencies on them from my application? I don't use Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Red Hat support empty `<jar-file></jar-file>` property is the solution. It works for me. So now my persistence.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="EAP" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/pscDataSource2</jta-data-source>

        <jar-file></jar-file> //fix

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.myPackage.interceptor.DelegatingInterceptor" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this tag inside my persistence.xml and it worked for me. may be you should try it cause am using eclipselink implementation of JPA

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Comment: this option I also tried but still the same error: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyEntity is not mapped

Comment: can you please post your persistence.xml file. Could it be that you use another provider?